# Accessing Maven repositories with Buildr using SSL certificates?

Tags: ssl, alfresco, buildr

I wanted to take Buildr for a spin, and wanted to use it for a project that is using Alfresco.
The Alfresco projects is maintaining a Maven repository at :
https://artifacts.alfresco.com

As you can see, it is using https.

I try to download 2 jars + dependencies to the class path  by declaring:

`ALFRESCO_CORE= transitive('org.alfresco:alfresco-core:jar:4.2.b')`

`ALFRESCO_REPOSITORY= transitive('org.alfresco:alfresco-repository:jar:4.2.b')`

The buildfile fails with the following error message:

`Requesting https://artifacts.alfresco.com/org/alfresco/alfresco-core/4.2.b/alfresco-core-4.2.b.pom
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
Buildr aborted!
RuntimeError : Failed to download org.alfresco:alfresco-core:pom:4.2.b, tried the following repositories:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
https://artifacts.alfresco.com/`

I believe, that this is due to the fact, that buildr doesn't trust the maven repositories certificate?

How can I make it accept the certificate? Alternatively, skip certificate validation?

Currently, it is a major showstopper that I can't access the repository :(

I hope somebody can give a hint how to proceed!
Agata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session`

This part of the message indicates that ruby won't be attempting to verify the certificate, so I don't think this is an SSL issue.

It appears that there is indeed no artifact at the URL in the error message:

```
$ curl -v -IHEAD https://artifacts.alfresco.com/org/alfresco/alfresco-core/4.2.b/alfresco-core-4.2.b.pom
[...]
> HEAD /org/alfresco/alfresco-core/4.2.b/alfresco-core-4.2.b.pom HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: artifacts.alfresco.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

This suggests either a problem with the artifact name or with the repository. Peter's working example uses the repository `https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/`. From the error message's URL, it looks like you are using `https://artifacts.alfresco.com/`. Can you try Peter's repository URL?

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to reproduce this problem ad at least from here the ssl certificate appears to be valid. The buildfile which I used to test this is;

```
repositories.remote << 'https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'
repositories.remote << 'https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots/'
repositories.remote << 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'

project 'foo' do
  project.group = 'x'
  project.version = 'x'
  compile.with transitive('org.alfresco:alfresco-core:jar:4.2.b')
end
```

However if the SSL certificate is not valid and you don't care you should be able to monkey patch the buildr class by adding a file tasks/ssl_fix.rake with the following content

```
module URI
  class HTTP
    def connect
      if proxy = proxy_uri
        proxy = URI.parse(proxy) if String === proxy
        http = Net::HTTP.new(host, port, proxy.host, proxy.port, proxy.user, proxy.password)
      else
        http = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
      end
      if self.instance_of? URI::HTTPS
        require 'net/https'
        # Patch so verifying is not a problem
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
        http.use_ssl = true
      end
      yield http
    end
  end
end
```

HTH